# Does capturing outgoing frames using linux raw socket require ETH_P_ALL

Tags: linux, packet-capture, raw-sockets

On Linux (2.6.39 kernel), using raw sockets, I'm trying to receive all the multicast frames that are sent out by the system itself.

I created a raw socket `socket(AF_PACKET, SOCK_RAW, htons(ETH_P_IP));`, and was reading the frames from the socket, throwing out frames that don't have destination address start with '01:00:5e'. I know there are better ways to latch on UDP, but I was playing around, and I noticed this particular problem, so below is the only scope of this question.

I could capture all the multicast packets flying around, except for the packets that are produced by the system where the program was running. The only way that I could make it start capturing system's own packets (along with packets coming to it) were to change the `protocol` parameter in the `socket()` call to `htons(ETH_P_ALL)`. The packets that I captured that way still had type of `0x0800` which is `ETH_P_IP`.

So I'm wondering about this - Is using `ETH_P_ALL` the only way to capture outgoing frames same as incoming frames? Is there any other way to specify direction of the packets captured?

`packet(7)` is bit vague on the subject, and only says:

> All incoming packets of that protocol type will be passed to the packet socket before they are passed to the protocols implemented in the kernel.

Answer (score 0):

Use libpcap to capture all the incoming and outgoing packets and use pcap_setdirection() to specify a direction that packets will be captured.
libpcap is faster then raw socket, as it uses PF_PACKET internally.

Comment: The last sentence makes no sense. PF_PACKET is the same thing as AF_PACKET which the asker is trying to use.